# Is it possible to change keyboard shortcuts in Microsoft Word Online

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, office365

I am using Microsoft Word online. Is there a way to change keyboard shortcuts? Microsoft's [online documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Word-Online-4ccbb899-f71e-4206-be6f-1d30c7d1bd13) doesn't say one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

There is no interface to change the word online keyboard shortcuts.  You can propose this thru their UserVoice channel https://word.uservoice.com/forums/271331-word-online  It doesn't appear to be something that has actually been asked for as of yet, though there are some variations of it thru other shortcut requests.